# Eclipse shows that there is expected semi-colon on JavaScript file when I don't believe there should be

Tags: javascript, eclipse

[image]

Hi I am trying to add google map api to my web app project and this code is from the google api documentation. I'm trying to do this on eclipse and the errors on 57-59 all say "Semi-colon expected". And due to this error I think the html is not able to call this js file. When I did this on VS Code, I didn't have any issue. I don't understand why this error occurs and I'm not sure if I need to install and js related extension.

```
function openMap() {
    console.log("Open Map");
    let map;

    async function initMap() {
    
        const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
        const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
        const curr_pos = { lat: 34.02116, lng: -118.287132 };
        map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: { lat: 34.02116, lng: -118.287132 },
            zoom: 8,
            mapId: "My Map",
        });
```

Comment: Is your Eclipse setup configured for a modern version of JavaScript?

Comment: I installed Eclipse couple of months ago but I don't remember doing anything for Javascript. Is that configuration a necessary extra step?

Comment: Things like `async` and destructuring are JavaScript features introduced since 2015 or so. An out-of-date JavaScript parser won't understand.

Comment: When I take out `async` , there's a new error saying that " 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules." So I am guessing it is up to date..?

Comment: Look I'm not sure what's going on, but Eclipse for whatever reason is not parsing your code correctly.

Comment: @Pointy Eclipse uses the language server from VS Code to provide latest state-of-the-art support for TypeScript and JavaScript. Syntax highlighting seems fine to me, so I don't see a problem with parsing. I cannot reproduce this in Eclipse 2023-09 (just a few "...is declared but its value is never read").